# Trello API showing zero boards

Tags: api, trello

I have a free Trello account. I connected successfully using 
https://api.trello.com/1/members/username?&key=[application_key]

IT gives all my details but the boards are zero when I have more than 10 of them.

"idBoards": [0]

They are not public boards.

Comment: I just realised the private boards need a key and a token. How do I get a token https://api.trello.com/1/members/username?&key=[application_key]&token[how do i get this]

Answer (score 1):

If you go to https://trello.com/app-key you see your Key, and underneath you can see how to generate your Token.

In order to get your own boards, you can use:

`https://api.trello.com/1/members/me/boards?token=[token]&key=[key]`

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out. you need both the token and the key. Got both and is not working.

You can get the key from https://trello.com/app-key after logging into Trello.

You can manually get a tocken from https://trello.com/1/authorize?expiration=never&scope=read,write,account&response_type=token&name=Server%20Token&key=c6cb4cb3dc70bb82cb0715184b3280f6